# Updating a preserved state in Windows Phone 8

Tags: caching, mvvm, windows-phone-8, pivot

I have an MVVM WP8 app that loads a large Pivot to start.  From one of my pivots, users can filter one of the lists on that pivot item.  I want to display the filter options on a separate page, process the filter on my list, and then redirect them back to the pivot in its prior state - while at the same time, updating the list on my pivot item with the filtered list.

I don't want to reload my entire pivot at that point, I want to go back to the pivot I came from and update its data context/items source only.

What's a good strategy for getting something like this done?